# copy models instance in django not working well

Tags: python, django, django-models, copy, deep-copy

I want to copy blogpost model, i have consider foreign key relationship but still fail in test of blog_copy and blog_author_copy. Could anyone help me?

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def copy(self):
        new = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        new.pk = None
        new.id = None
        new.date_created = datetime.now()
        # new.author.blog_posts.add(new)
        authors = Author.objects.all()
        for author in authors:
            if self.author == author:
                author.blog_posts.add(new)
        new.save()
        old = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        for comment in old.comments.all():
            comment.pk = None
            comment.blog_post = new
            comment.save()
            new.comments.add(comment)
            new.save()

class Comment(models.Model):
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented like this:

```
    def copy(self):
        blog_copy = self
        blog_copy.pk = None
        blog_copy.id = None
        blog_copy.date_created = datetime.now()
        blog_copy.author = self.author
        blog_copy.save()

        comments_copy = []
        for comment in self.comments.all():
            comment.pk = None
            comment.id = None
            comment.blog_post = blog_copy
            comments_copy.append(comment)

        Comment.objects.bulk_create(comments_copy)
        return blog_copy
```

`self` is the instance itself, so no need to get it from the db separately. For the `author`, you can just get the current one using `self.author` (same idea for `comments`).